# laserscan to 3D point cloud

Tags: rviz, laser, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with the Hokuyo laser scanner. The scanner is fixed in the robot. There is no option for application of tilt to the scanner. Now I would like to generate the 3D point cloud from the scan data. In the laser assembler node I found that it must receive set of scan data due to the tilt of the sensor. I donot need so much detailed map. All I want to extrude the line in Rviz along z axis ,I get from the laser scan data (single set). Is it possible?? If yes how?? I really stuck in here. thanks in advance.....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198525/laserscan-to-3d-point-cloud/) by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2014-11-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-11-28**:
I think you're gonna have to do that yourself.

**Comment by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on 2014-11-28**:
I found one package for orthogonal projection. but I need continous extrusion of the line upto the gorund.

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2015-05-28**:
@Robot did you implement that function? I have the same need. So it would be helpful to know what is the best way to do that. Regards

**Comment by [bomdaworld](https://answers.ros.org/users/27993/bomdaworld/) on 2016-09-15**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/11232/how-to-turn-laser-scan-to-point-cloud-map/
The answers here provide a pretty decent example, just edit the variables to fit your needs. The high-fidelity function requires a tf broadcaster whilst the low-fidelity doesn't.
Refer to link to laser_geometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's a bit of an esoteric need, so you'll probably have to write your own node to make the conversion.

The simplest approach would be to use the tools in [laser_geometry](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_geometry) to initially convert the laserscan into a pointcloud. Then iterate through each point in the cloud and 'extrude' it by adding additional points with different z values, with whatever your required density is.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-12-02**:
@Robot if this answer is good for you, please mark it as the answer, thanks!